# Does anyone know why my site navigation links aren't working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have put together a tabular style navigation bar, within each one I have put  tags with links to the rest of the site.

Here is the code:

```
<li class="">
                            <a href="#section-shape-3">
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                                <span><a href="login.html">Login</a></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
```

Without the  tags that link to the login.html page, the visual of the menu works well with the respective .css and .js files just like it should. When I add the  tag to make a connection with the login.html page, the visual of the tab distorts and ruins the look, and also doesn't do anything when clicked, not linking up to the login.html page.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Your link is not working because you have nested anchor tags. When you try to click on "Login" the browser thinks you are clicking on the parent anchor and probably jumping to the top of the page and adding #section-shape-3 to the end of your url. You should never nest anchor tags inside eachother.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a hyperlink from within an already-open hyperlink. Don't forget to close the first link before opening the second one :)

I believe the way in which you want to display the two links would look like this:

```html
<li class="">
  <a href="#section-shape-3">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use>
    </svg>
  </a>
  <span>
    <a href="login.html">Login</a>
  </span>
</li>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately when the code in this way, the background colour of the tab goes to transparent, the size of the text expands by a couple of factors, and when clicked, there is still no redirect to the Login page. I can't see what is causing it.

Comment: @Andrew -- Those issues are from your CSS. Could you please update your answer so that all relevant CSS is included as well? In fact, including the entire navigation bar's HTML would help too. It's a difficult balance between posting too little and too much, but I'm afraid there's not enough for me to look at with regards to display issues as it stands :)

Comment: Okay I have put the code together in this jsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net  as it is slightly over 1000 lines I didn't want to post it all here, would that work?

Comment: @Andrew -- JSFiddle is a great site for posting code to StackOverflow. However, be aware that most people won't want to read through literally over 1000 lines of code. What you should try and do is work out the section of code causing the issue through trial and error. Obviously we wouldn't need *all* of your CSS, just the parts that target anything to do with the navbar -- what you really need is a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then post that in a JSFiddle :)